How to upload a file to a server along with form data that is sent to Google Sheets using fetch?
I need to create a field for uploading files (PDF, JPG) to a server. The problem is that my contact form sends data to a Google Sheet using fetch. I don't know how to add code that will send the file to the server without affecting the other data that's sent from the form to the Google Sheet.
document.getElementById('open-form-link').addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  document.getElementById('popup-form').style.display = 'block'; 
});

document.getElementById('close-form-btn').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  document.getElementById('popup-form').style.display = 'none'; 
});

window.onclick = function(event) { 
  if (event.target == document.getElementById('popup-form')) {   
    document.getElementById('popup-form').style.display = 'none';  
  }
};
 
const scriptURL = '...'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet'] 
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {  
  e.preventDefault()
  document.getElementById('timestamp').value = new Date().toLocaleString('uk-UA', {    
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'  
  });
    
  fetch(scriptURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new FormData(form)
  })  .then(response => {   
    console.log('Success!', response)    document.getElementById('contactForm').style.display = 'none';   
    document.getElementById('success-message').style.display = 'block';  
  })  .catch(error => {   
    console.error('Error!', error.message)    alert('An error occurred when sending the form. Please try again later.');  
  })   
});

function openForm() { 
  document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() { 
  document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display = "none";
}

I tried using FormData to append both my file and the other form data from my contact form. I then used fetch to send this FormData object to my server, expecting the file to be uploaded and the form data to be sent to Google Sheets.
I'm not sure how to modify my code to handle both the file upload and the Google Sheets submission simultaneously.

you can append a file (or any other variable) in a FormData object

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script, Google Spreadsheet, and The problem is that my contact form sends data to a Google Sheet using fetch.. Can I ask you about the details of your current situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

@Tanaike
I meant that the fetch call which has a link to Google Sheets const scriptURL = '...' sends data there, but I also need to send a file to the server where my PHP script will process this file and save it in a specific folder. In other words, how can I send data to Google Sheets and simultaneously send a file to the server in one request (if possible)?

@ADyson I added an formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);, but as far as I understand, my PHP script doesn't accept the file.
const formData = new FormData(form); // Create FormData from form
formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]); // Add file to FormData
// 2. Send file to server
const fileData = new FormData();
fileData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);
fetch('../upload.php', {
method: 'POST',
body: fileData
})

I thought you were sending the data to Google, not to your own php script?

The point is that I have a form on my website, and when a user fills out the form, the data is sent to Google Sheets. However, recently it became necessary to add another field to the contact form, this field being input type="file", which means that the uploaded file needs to be stored on our server (unfortunately, this is a requirement). Therefore, I created upload.php.

Ok. So you need 1 fetch() request going to google, and another fetch() request going to your PHP script. Have you got that? You posted some code in the comments but it's  not clear how they fit into the context of the code in your question. And if the upload to PHP is the problem, you need to [edit] your question to integrate that code into your existing sample, and we also need to see the PHP code which you've written to receive and process that. See also how to make a [mre] of your issue.

PHP can normally receive a file uploaded via AJAX/form-data no problem at all, but obviously without seeing all the relevant code in context we can't see easily if you've made any particular mistake.
